# UIWebView is not shown

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview

WebView in Mainstoryboard is not shown anything. I wanna show yahoo page in my app.When I run my app in an emulator(that is not my real iPhone), it is like only　black screen.

Any error does not happen in that time, but
[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r3VV.png)

In this part, I got a warning

> "signal SIGABRT"

My code is like

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import UIKit

class webViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webBrowser: UIWebView! = nil

    var targetURL = "https://www.yahoo.co.jp"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //loadAddressURL()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadAddressURL() {
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: targetURL)
        let req = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL as! URL)
        webBrowser.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)
    }



}
```

I think a connection of WebView & WebViewController is ok. I tried to do Add Exception Breakpoint,and find a point of this error.
The result is 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfGwx.png)

My app dropped in

> "Thread1:breakpoint4.1".

What is wrong with my app?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign `nil` value to `@IBOutlet var webBrowser: UIWebView!`.

Leave:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webBrowser: UIWebView!
```

BTW, I'm assuming that you create correctly `@IBOutlet` by holding `ctr` and dragging from storyboard to you view controller. But I'm afraid that because of lack `weak` next to your `@IBOutlet` you created it manually in code so you need to clip it to the view in storyboard

Comment: thx, ur comment.I tried ur code, but I got  same error "result" in my question "Thread1:breakpoint4.1".How can I fix this?

Comment: how you connected UIWebView from storyboard with ViewController? You should do it in this way https://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/creating-outlets-and-actions-via-drag-and-drop-in-xcode-4/ not manually (it is possible of course doing this fully manually but it is bit more complex)

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webBrowser: UIWebView!
    var targetURL = "https://www.yahoo.co.jp"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.loadAddressURL()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadAddressURL() {
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: targetURL)
        let req = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)
        webBrowser.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)
    }
}
```

Use this.

Comment: thx, ur comment.I tried ur code, but I got  same error "result" in my question "Thread1:breakpoint4.1".How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**CTRL** + **DRAG** to create `IBOutlet` for `UIWebView` like mentioned in below image and it should be:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webBrowser: UIWebView!
```

[image]

Initialize your `targetURL` like :

```
let targetURL = "https://www.yahoo.co.jp".addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Then in your func `loadAddressURL` must be

```
func loadAddressURL() {

        if NSURL(string: targetURL!) != nil {

            let url = URL(string: targetURL!)!
            webBrowser.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))

        }

    }
```

Comment: thx, ur comment.I tried ur code, but I got  same error "result" in my question "Thread1:breakpoint4.1".How can I fix this?